# Knockout Observable Array is not a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I'm trying to access a Knockout Observable array but I'm getting an error message saying it is not a function. I'm trying to use a nested structure for my viewmodel. When I try to access my observable array by accessing it as `this.dsaModel().regions()` I get an error saying "regions is not a function".

I receive the JSON from my WebAPI using this call

```
module Sontag.Map.Services {
export class DsaDataValueService {
    private _baseUrl = '/umbraco/api/dsaapi/';

    getDsaData(): Q.Promise<Models.DsaModel> {
        return Q($.getJSON(this._baseUrl + 'getalldsadata'));
    }
}
```

}

The JSON comes back looking like this from the API:

```js
{
  "regions": [
    {
      "id": 1258,
      "name": "Canada",
      "institutes": [
        {
          "id": 1223,
          "name": "The Hospital for Sick Children",
          "location": "Toronto, Ontario Canada",
          "regionId": 1258,
          "latitude": null,
          "longitude": null,
          "recipients": [
            {
              "id": 1224,
              "name": "Michael D. Taylor",
              "title": "",
              "education": "M.D.,Ph.D.",
              "yearAwarded": 2007,
              "fieldOfStudy": "Cancer Genomics",
              "instituteId": 1223,
              "fieldOfStudyId": 1285,
              "regionId": 1258,
              "url": "/grants/brain-cancer/dsa-map/recipients/michael-d-taylor/"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Currently my viewmodel looks like this.

```
module Map.ViewModels {
    export class DsaViewModel implements IActivatable {      
        constructor(private _dsaDataValueService: Services.DsaDataValueService) {
        }

        public dsaModel = ko.observable<Models.DsaModel>();
        public filteredDsaData = ko.observable<Models.DsaModel>();
        public isActivated: boolean = false;


        activate() {
            this.getDsaData();
        }

        getDsaData() {
            this._dsaDataValueService.getDsaData()
                .done(data => {
                    this.dsaModel(data);

                });
        }
    }
}
```

And the Model looks like this.

```
module Map.Models {
    export class DsaModel {
        constructor(jsObject?: {}) {
            if (jsObject) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(jsObject, {}, this);
            }
        }
        public regions = ko.observableArray<Models.RegionModel>();

        //Filter options
        public institutesSelectList = ko.observableArray<Models.SelectListModel>();
        public regionsSelectList = ko.observableArray<Models.SelectListModel>();
        public fieldsOfStudySelectList = ko.observableArray<Models.SelectListModel>();
    }
}
```

The issue comes when I try to filter the observable array like this:

```
var filteredRegions = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.dsaModel().regions(),
                        region => region.id() === this.selectedRegion());
                    this.dsaModel().regions(filteredRegions);
                    return this.dsaModel();
```

When I pass "this.dsaModel().regions()" as a parameter to the ko.utils.arrayFilter call I'm getting an error message saying "regions is not a function"

Comment: @Paarth I'm trying to filter the elements of that knockout observable using ko.utils.arrayFilter.

Comment: @Paarth I think you're off track a bit, the result of `ko.observableArray()` *is* a function (or at least it should be).

Comment: OP, could you try to change up your code a bit so it becomes a [mcve]? There's a few bits missing that might be important (e.g. how you bootstrap everything), and there's quite a few bits that are probably irrelevant (e.g. all sorts of other properties) making it hard to understand the situation.

Comment: @Jeroen I went ahead and added all of the components that I'm using and included the exact snippet of code that is giving me the error. Thank you for looking at this issue, I'm a bit stumped at the moment.

Comment: Could you show us the values of `this.dsaModel()` and `this.dsaModel().regions` at the time of the error?